# Method handle does not exist error on laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, middleware

get this error when I am using any custom middleware (specified in **$routeMiddleware** Array) for routes.

```
Route::get('/foo', function() { 
    return "foo";
});
```

works fine. but

```
Route::get('/foo', function() { 
    return "foo";
})->middleware('auth');
```

the above one throw

**BadMethodCallException** Method handle does not exist.

Note: got this error after updated from laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.4

From my log

```
[2017-08-29 12:22:35] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method handle does not exist. in /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:74
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php(294): Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard->__call('handle', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->__call('handle', Array)
#2 /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Comment: am not logged in. but if not logged in it should redirected to login page right?

Comment: Have you scaffolded `Auth`..? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: yes @ZaheerAttar

Comment: Just tried this on a fresh 5.4 laravel install and there it works fine. Only thing I can think of is to dumpautoload.

Comment: @Anders I also tried with fresh laravel 5.4 and it works fine. tried dumpautoload too. but same issue

Comment: Did you follow the Upgrade Guide of Laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade Did you clear route cache? "php artisan route:clear"

Comment: In the stack trace what class is throwing the exception i.e. what class does it say is missing the `handle` method?

Comment: @RossWilson Slack trace added.

Comment: Can you check your bootstrap/app.php file? You should map Authentication Middleware before using it. Something like follows;
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
]);

Comment: Already mapped Authentication middleware class in $routeMiddleware array in app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: Post your  $routeMiddleware Array.